# Custom Dialog with PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat and DialogPreference(v7)

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate a TimePicker into the preferences screen like the one on a Lollipop device's Date&Time settings screen :

[image]

These are my classes so far :

```
public class SettingsFragment extends android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

public class TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat extends android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat

TimeDialogPreference extends android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference
```

I've found sample code for android.preference.DialogPreference on the net but I couldn't find any support.v7 code samples. There are only bits and pieces on the net explaining only partially what I want to do. The best solution was posted here [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621403/how-do-i-create-custom-preferences-using-android-support-v7-preference-library) but unfortunately it doesn't contain enough information.

Can anybody provide a sample implementation and / or link to a tutorial/working sample for the v7 support library preference dialog API ?

Comment: Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34398747/1283501)